# iOS SDK global error handler for errors from server

Tags: ios, asynchronous, error-handling, afhttprequestoperation

I have a class called Request. A request is asynchronous. At the end of the  request, I check the response for a server error. If there is a server error, I send out a notification.

```
+(BOOL)checkForResponseError:(NSArray*)response{
    if ([[response objectAtIndex:1] boolValue] == YES) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Server Error" object:nil userInfo:@{@"error":response[0]}];
        NSLog(@"Server Response Error %@", response[0]);
        return YES;
        //[NSException raise:@"Server error on response" format:@"Response error: %@", response[0]];
    }else if(response == nil){
        NSLog(@"nil response");
        #ifdef DEBUG
            [NSException raise:@"Error 500" format:@"Check the logs for more information"];
        #endif
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

+(Request*)request{
Request *request = [[Request alloc] init];

request.success = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObj) {
    NSLog(@"Success on operation %@ with result %@", [operation.request.URL absoluteString], operation.responseString);
    NSArray *result = responseObj;
    if (![Request checkForResponseError:result]){
        request.completion(result);
    }
};

request.failure = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Error: %@, result %@", error.localizedDescription, operation.responseString);
    #ifdef DEBUG
        [NSException raise:@"action failed" format:@"Link %@ Failed with objective c error: %@", [operation.request.URL absoluteString], error];
    #endif
};

return request;
}

-(AFHTTPRequestOperationManager*)getWithAction:(NSString *)action parameters:(NSDictionary*)params success:(void (^)(NSArray*))c{
    NSLog(@"Getting with action %@ and params %@", action, params);

    completion = c;
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [Header requestOperationManager];

    [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, action]  parameters:params success:success failure:failure];

    return manager;
}
```

The above are the relevant methods in the response class. Now- whenever the request throws up a Server Error notification, no matter where it is in the app, I need the app to show an alert immediately. So I thought to simply put a handler in the application delegate as such:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"Server Error" object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notif){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:[notif userInfo][@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}];
```

Problem is, that when there is an error, the app will freeze for a few minutes and then show the alert. I understand this has something to do with the application lifecycle. Is there a way to achieve what I want (from a code simplicity standpoint), and not have the app freeze for a few minutes?I just don't have any idea how to solve this.

Thank you!

Comment: No way it's the application lifecycle ... remember the notification is raised in a background thread, so maybe you should show the alert on the main thread? It might be that the next drawing cycle is happening sometime in the future when you don't ...

Comment: How would I show it on the main thread?

Comment: Use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // show alertview });

Comment: Works! Thank you. Please write your answer so I can award you with the correct answer